# Suppress or remove python tabula-py warnings

Tags: python, pdf, tabula

I have python code using [tabula-py](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py) for reading PDF to extract the text and then change it to tabular form via tabula-py. But it gives me a warning.

```
Nov 15, 2017 3:40:23 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont toUnicode
WARNING: No Unicode mapping for .notdef (9) in font Helvetica
```

This warning is of [tabula-py](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py), And [Tabula-py](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py) is written in Java. So I cannot simply use `-W ignore` to suppress the above warning.

**Is there any way to remove or suppress the above warning.**

Comment: I believe this is related to this: https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java/issues/115

Comment: I have used argument silent=True. however, it's not suppressed any warning messages.. does anyone has an answer for this ?

Comment: Is there a problem with the PDF file?  See https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/PDFBOX-3296.  Can you share a sample PDF that produces this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tabula-py author is here. Setting `silent=True` suppresses the tabula-java logs.
see also:
https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/blob/e11d6f0ac518810b6d92b60a815e34f32f6bf085/tabula/io.py#L65
https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.build_options

Comment: This doesn't seem to work I still get the following for each page:
"Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment\trusted.certs"

Answer (score 3):

Tabula provides a built in feature to suppress java warning.

Try `silent=True` parameter in request:

```
tabula.read_pdf("/path/to/sample.pdf", pages="all", silent=True)
```

[Documentation Source](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.build_options)